# Match data from two different files

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, perl

In order to have a record of the devices connected to a network I'm working on an `Expect` script that takes information from the command `Show CDP neighbors detail` and saves certain fields including `Device Name, IP address, Interface and Port ID (outgoing port)`, any of those fields work as a primary key in my Database, not even IP address cause the same IP address doesn't guaranty it is the same device. For that reason I need to catch the S/N of each device with the command `show inventory`, I've got both command's output in separate text files and now I need to match the information.

file1:

```
Device ID: BIOTERIO
  IP address: 000.000.00.001
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/6,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
  IP address: 000.000.0.002
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/1,  Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/23
Device ID: LAB_PESADO
 --More--           IP address: 000.000.000.003
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/11,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 000.000.000.003
Device ID: Arquitectura_Salones
  IP address: 000.000.000.04
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/9,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/49
  IP address: 000.000.000.04
Device ID: CIVIL_253
  IP address: 000.000.000.005
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/4,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet1/0/52
  IP address: 000.000.000.005
Device ID: Arquitectura
  IP address: 000.000.000.006
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/3,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 000.000.000.006
Device ID: ING_CIVIL_DIR
  IP address: 000.000.0.007
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/10,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
Device ID: ING_CIVIL
  IP address: 000.000.000.008
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/7,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/2
  IP address: 000.000.000.008
Device ID: Ingenieria_Posgrado
  IP address: 000.000.000.009
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/8,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 000.000.000.009
Device ID: Biblio_Barragan
  IP address: 000.000.000.10
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/2,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 000.000.000.10
Device ID: Electronica_Edif_3
  IP address: 000.000.000.011
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/5,  Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
  IP address: 000.000.000.011
]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-NoteBook-PC: ~cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-NoteBook-PC:~$ awk '/Device ID|IP address|Interface|Port ID/ { print }' CDPdet.dat >tabladetallada.dat
```

file 2:

```
show inventory
NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C3750G-12S"
PID: WS-C3750G-12S-E   , VID: V06, SN: FDO1130Z9ZJ

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/1", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K082        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/2", DESCR: "10/100/1000BaseTX SFP"
PID: GLC-T               , VID:    , SN: 00000MTC1666080Z

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/3", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H118K083        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/4", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K041        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/5", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: FNS11140FLE     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/6", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: P7K06UQ         

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/7", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K052        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/8", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: H006K030        

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/9", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID:                     , VID:    , SN: FNS14200533     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/10", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS14201SG0     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/11", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS174202FT     

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/0/12", DESCR: "1000BaseLX SFP"
PID: GLC-LH-SMD          , VID: V86, SN: FNS184203FS     


Barragan_3750>
```

I would like to have all the information placed in the same file and in the correct order, something like this:

```
Device ID: BIOTERIO
IP address: 000.000.00.001
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/6  
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: P7K06UQ

Device ID: N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
IP address: 000.000.0.002
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/1  
Port ID (outgoing port): Ethernet7/23
SN: H006K082

Device ID: LAB_PESADO
IP address: 000.000.000.003
Interface: GigabitEthernet1/0/11
Port ID (outgoing port): GigabitEthernet0/1
SN: FNS174202FT
...
etc
```

Does anybody know how to do that using grep, awk or perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1=file1
FILE2=file2

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == Device\ ID* ]]; then
        echo -e "\n$line"
        expectIp=1
    elif [[ $line == *IP\ address* && $expectIp -eq 1 ]]; then
        sed 's/^\s*//' <<< $line
        unset expectIp
    elif [[ $line == Interface* ]]; then
        interface=$(echo $line | grep -o 'Interface[^,]*,' | sed 's/,//')
        echo $interface
        echo $line | grep -o 'Port ID.*'
        justInterface=$(echo $interface | sed 's/Interface: //')
        grep -A1 \"$justInterface\" $FILE2 | grep -o 'SN: .*'
    fi
done < $FILE1
```